# Import cordova 6.0.0 project into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I have a project generated with cordova Command-Line Interface. I was always able to import cordova projects into eclipse JUNO without problems. Always got in eclipse two folders, one for NAMEDPROJECT and another called NAMEPROJECT_cordovalib. And configure NAMEPROJECT for reference cordovalib.

But now when I try to import a cordova 6.0.0 project into eclipse workspace it shows a lot of folders (MainActivity, aapt, debug, 13.1.0, CordovaLib). Why this amount of folders? I only import from the platforms/Android/ folder in the cordova CML project.
Doesn't work so far no matter which one I import.

Using android API 23, Eclipse Luna (4.4.2) , cordova 6.0.0.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: are you really using [phonegap-desktop-app](http://phonegap.com/getstarted/) ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to import only "MainActivity" and "CordovaLib" only, you are not facing any problem

[image]